# Как проксировать подключение к PostgreSQL, с помощью nginx?

Tags: postgresql, nginx, proxy, pgadmin4

**Схема.** Публичный прокси-сервер на nginx. Он проксирует HTTP-запросы на другой сервер в частной сети. На этом частном сервере запущено Django-приложение, которое использует  PostgreSQL. База находится на этом же частном сервере.

**Задача.** Нужно настроить доступ к базе, для того, чтобы *можно было подключаться через pgAdmin4. Через HTTPS.*

**Что сделано?**

1. Настроен доступ к базе из прокси-сервера ([инструкция](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003321434-How-to-enable-remote-access-to-PostgreSQL-server-on-a-Plesk-server-)).
2. Добавлен nginx-конфиг для прокси.

**Вопрос.** Я понимаю, что в данной случае, нельзя просто проксировать запросы, как с HTTP. Поиски в гугле ничего не дали. Единственное на что обратил внимание, это то, что, возможно, здесь нужно использовать nginx-кий stream. *Так ли это? Нужно смотреть в сторону stream? Если у кого-то есть материал о том, как это сделать, буду благодарен.* :)

Comment: postgresql работает по собственному протоколу, никакого отношения к http(s) не имеющему. Так что да, необходим stream, так как он дает сырое tcp соединение.

Comment: @Mike, спасибо за комментарий!